# Can't sign with imported to AndroidKeyStore RSA Private key

Tags: android, kotlin, rsa, signing, android-keystore

I'm trying to use an imported keystore key to sign a a piece of data:

My Key is first generated outside of AndroidKeyStore (that is on purpose)
and then imported into AndroidKeyStore

using the following way:

```
    val keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
    keyGen.initialize(2048)
    val keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair()

    val keyProtectionSign = KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or //
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY).setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256) //

            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1) //
            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .build()
    keyStore.setEntry(signatureAlias,
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(keyPair.private, arrayOf(certificate)),
            keyProtectionSign)
```

After that I am trying to use the key to sign:

```
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keyStore.load(null)
    val privateKey = keyStore.getKey(signatureAlias,null)
    val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
    signature.initSign(privateKey)
    signature.update(data)
    val sign = signature.sign()
```

However, the line `signature.initSign(privateKey)` throws an Exception: `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance`

If i do not import the key into the android keystore, and try to sign with that, it works.

If i generate the key directly in the AndroidKeyStore it also fails with the same error.

What is wrong with my code? Why can't i sign with my RSA key?

Comment: `keyStore.load(null)` appears questionable. This usually should be an input stream.

Comment: that's actually the only setting that is allowed

Comment: I don't think so. Why should a method only accept `null` as argument?

Comment: because the specific implementation i am using (AndroidKeyStore) throws an exception if you try to pass a parameter

Comment: This might indeed differ in between the key-store types, assuming an on-device key-store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check out the issues discussed in this thread:

https://markmail.org/message/4omngfbqzdq3wk3b#query:+page:1+mid:ne47xbhggf6samib+state:results

> Unfortunately, Bouncy Castle 
>   JCA Provider has a bug (http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-543 
>   https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BJA-543&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNEErNOODYZHHZomGgR1y7NLq2yegw)
>   where is advertises to JCA that it can handle any keys, even those that it 
>   actually can't handle
>
> ...
>
> If you must install the Bouncy Castle JCA Provider, install it below 
>   Android Keystore JCA provider. The best way to achieve that is to find the 
>   index at which the platform-bundled Bouncy Castle provider is installed, 
>   and then invoke Security.insertProviderAt with that same index and your 
>   Bouncy Castle Provider.

Comment: So then: the OP's problem was she had installed the bouncycastle provider in front of the Android KeyStore provider?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. To actually fix the problem i first ran remove the provider, and then add the provider in last